# How i can access my webpage from my public ip in my own network

Tags: node.js, web, redirect, ip

Let me explain a little more, I have hosted a page in my PC number 1 with the domain following my public IP this.com when I want to access to the domain with PC number 2 in the same network I cant... the only way is from the local IP from PC number 1 or outside the network, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you open ports of  PC number 2 ? If you didnt open ports you can not access

Comment: yes, if i try by ip local like 192.168.bla.bla I can but in the public IP from the internet provider can't access to it in PC 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a public ID I think you will need to do some Port Forwarding configuration in the router to let the router know that this port is going to PC 1's port.

Read the manual of your router to see how it's done, I think once you do that everything will work for you.

The other potential issue could be a local firewall on PC 1, in which case you need to make sure that the port is available and open in the firewall as well.

Comment: any tutorial where i can see how to that?

Comment: Hey, please look into the manual for your router's model... Every model has it in different places it's usually called "Port Forwarding" but basically the idea is that you let your router know where to point the incoming traffic to